# What will happen if I bring a positively charged body near the negative terminal of battery?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, voltage, batteries

Will the electrons flow from negative terminal of the battery to the charged body so as to neutralized a charged body..thus causing a decrease in pd of  battery

Comment: *"thus causing a decrease in pd of battery"* - I don't understand your reasoning here; a battery (cell) is not like a capacitor. Why do you say that the potential difference [across the battery terminals] would decrease?

Answer (score 1):

(a) I'll assume that the positive charged body is a *conductor* and that it is *touched* on to the negative terminal of the battery.

(b) Electrons will then flow from the negative battery terminal on to the body. The same amount of negative charge will be pumped through the battery from its positive terminal (and/or positive charge in the other direction).

(c) The flow of charge will stop (after a very short time) when the pd between the battery terminals is restored to its previous value. This value is the emf of the cell, in other words the work the battery can do, per coulomb of charge flowing through it, because of the chemical reactions inside it.

(d) The battery as a whole will have lost some electrons to the body, and will be at a positive potential with respect to infinity, but the pd between its terminals will not change (except for a very short-lived dip owing to its internal resistance).